# Errors with Sphero - iOS

Tags: ios, sphero-api, sphero

I got 22 errors when I tried to run my application (which connected to Sphero) on iPad:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      RKAchievementManager::getAchievements() in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
      RKAchievementManager::wsCallLoaded(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, int) in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
  "std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      RKAchievementManager::pullAchievements() in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
      RKAchievementManager::updateAchievementProgress() in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
      RKAchievementManager::pushAchievements() in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
      RKAchievementManager::getBallName() in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in RobotKit(RKAchievementManager.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your deployment target to iOS 6.0.  Be sure you have the linker flag -lstdc++